# Is there a way to blacklist PHP include() or require()'s access to file paths?

Tags: php, security, authentication, file-handling

This sounds like a dumb question, and the way I am doing this is not secure currently, so I want to be able to improve my security and reduce my chances of malicious use.

I have an "admin panel". I can add/remove users and appoint them admins and such. One of the permissions I might let them have is to edit files. This is a problem though since I store passwords in files and restrict web access to them (MySQL usage for the hosting provider is low) via `.htaccess`.

Because of this, I provide a file blacklist. However, the people can still see passwords if they edit a PHP file to `include()` or `require()` the login handling file and get the session key (which is what my login handling script can do) for the root account then hijack it and have root privileges.

Because of this I want to restrict `include`/`require` access.

The first idea I thought of is just simply checking if it is requiring/including the file in the code of the file they edited, but that seems too "risky".

Then, I wondered if I could restrict access of include/require of that certain file/certain files to only a list of specific php files (like the login/control panel files that need that login handler file).

If not, should I do away with a file editing feature altogether, since it seems quite risky even if I *do* find out how to limit access.

Comment: _"should I do away with a file editing feature altogether"_ YES. The web server should not have write access to the files it serves, never mind the remote users. This is just asking for a problem.

Comment: @AlexHowansky I was afraid so. In addition it also paves way to errors if the user doesn't correctly program the file.

Comment: Maybe you can take help of sessions?

Comment: @nice_dev Yeah but I already set it up to use cookies :/ It works fine anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[include()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) doesn't allow limiting the path to a specific folder. Same goes for `require()`, `require_once()`, `file_get_contents()`, `highlight_file()`, `fopen()`, etc...

You can change the default include path, but that's a different thing. It would still possible to include using an absolute or a different relative path. Or to simply print the file contents using a different function.

**So my recommendation is to really disallow editing files altogether.**

If you need users to be able to update text contents, consider using a translation engine (even for just one language). Possibly combined with markdown (stored MD in database, converted to HTML for display) or HTML output from wysiwyg editor if they need to be able to edit the styling as well.

Comment: Yeah simply allowing editing certain non-php files would be a breeze, since they can't actually use any `include` or `require` or such (like editing a txt file. Txt files wouldn't be executed so there isn't much harm there). Looks like this is probably the best way to go (I've never seen a website have source code editing features, anyways... probably for the better)